# UWP: Problem with binding and adding new items

Tags: uwp

So I am using a uwp datagrid control, this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

The ItemsSource of my grid is bound to an ObservableCollection. The user can click on an add button which inserts a new item to the collection: `AllPlans.Insert(0, newLessonPlan);`

It works well and good at first, until the user clicks on a toggle control which changes the collection, the toggle event:

```
 private void ToggleOldEvents_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             AllPlans = new ObservableCollection<Entities.LessonPlan>(PlanController.GetAll(((Entities.AppUser)UserBox.SelectedItem).id, ToggleOldEvents.IsOn).OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTimeFrom));
             PlansGrid.ItemsSource = AllPlans;
             foreach (var col in PlansGrid.Columns)
             {
                 col.SortDirection = null;
             }
         }
```

Then when the user tries to add another item to the collection, it falls over at `AllPlans.Insert(0, newLessonPlan);` It is saying that the index 0 is out of bounds.

Stack trace:

```
    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGridInternals.DataGridDisplayData.UnloadScrollingElement(Int32 slot, Boolean updateSlotInformation, Boolean wasDeleted)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.RemoveNonDisplayedRows(Int32 newFirstDisplayedSlot, Int32 newLastDisplayedSlot)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.UpdateDisplayedRows(Int32 newFirstDisplayedSlot, Double displayHeight)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.ComputeScrollBarsLayout()
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.OnAddedElement_Phase2(Int32 slot, Boolean updateVerticalScrollBarOnly)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.InsertRowAt(Int32 rowIndex)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Data.Utilities.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Data.Utilities.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(EffectiveNotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object oldItem, Object newItem, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
    at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Data.Utilities.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
    at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    at TeachItUWP.Pages.LessonPlanningPage.AddEvent_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\pavel\source\repos\TeachItUWP\TeachItUWP\Pages\LessonPlanningPage.xaml.cs:line 270
```

If I comment out the `PlansGrid.ItemsSource = AllPlans;` in my toggle event, I don't get the error, but then the user doesn't see the items in the collection on the grid.

Using `AllPlans.Add(newLessonPlan);` works, but I was trying to use `PlansGrid.ScrollIntoView(newLessonPlan, null);` which gives me `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'` after the same user behaviour described earlier.

Anyone had something like this?

---

I created a sample project which shows the error: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avf9IdqZIPdXi2GAxF5meYl7oxIv?e=CnJe4N

Upon further inspection it seems to be an issue with the user interface and when you use a RowDetailsTemplate in your grid.

In the sample project, if you click on the "Fill Long" button, it will change the collection so the grid has enough data that you can scroll, then when you click the "Add a Row" button the error occurs.

If you click the "Fill Short" button so there are only 2 rows and the grid can't be scrolled yet because there is not enough data, the error will not happen when you click "Add a Row", but if you click it again it will happen because the grid now has a scrollbar because there is more data in it now.

If you click the "Fill Short" button and then resize the window so it is less in height, when you click the "Add a Row" button the error will also happen.

Comment: Hello, I tried to create a DataGrid, and performed the operation of changing the data source and adding data to the new data source, and there was no exception. So can you provide a minimum runable demo so that we can analyze the specific cause of the problem?

Comment: Hello, I created a sample project which shows the error: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avf9IdqZIPdXi2GAxF5meYl7oxIv?e=CnJe4N

Upon further inspection it seems to be an issue with the user interface and when you use a RowDetailsTemplate in your grid. I edited my question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be an abnormal rendering and is caused by `RowDetailsTemplate`.

As a workaround, you can write this:

```cs
private void AddOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var randomGenerator = new Random();

    var entitity1 = new TestEntity();
    entitity1.Name = randomGenerator.Next(10, 999999).ToString();
    entitity1.Description = "New Random";
    TestGrid.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
    CollectionOfEntities.Insert(0,entitity1);
    TestGrid.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Visible;
}
```

Before inserting data, first set `RowDetailsVisibilityMode` to Collapsed, and then resume, so that no error will be reported.

You can also report this problem on [Github](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Hi, yes I found a similar work around by setting the grid ItemSource to null before the insert, and then setting it back to what it was after the insert. I don't have a github account so feel free to steal this find to report! 